# How to notify my plugin users about new version releases?

Tags: updates

I developed some WordPress plugins that I sell from my own website. Say, I released a plugin XXX (version 1.0) and someone purchased this.

Few days later, I released version 1.1 of that plugin. Now how do I notify that customer that this plugin has an update available?

Note: I use woocommerce to sell my plugins.

Comment: What about getting idea from this article: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/distributing-your-plugins-in-github-with-automatic-updates--wp-34817

Comment: the right answer is every way possible...

Answer (score 1):

You should integrate the ability to automatically update your plugin right through WordPress. [There is a tutorial that gives you some help on this.](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-the-wordpress-http-api-automatic-plugin-updates--wp-25181)

Just my personal view, but: **Please stay on the good side.**

Offer updates all the time, so your plugin stays up to date. I don´t want my site to get compromised because some *(enter impolite word of your choice here)* plugin developer/company thought it would be a great idea to ship his/their slider plugin with dozens of themes but never bring out updates for it, unless you buy the plugin again. Which results in (hundreds of) thousands sites to get hacked.

Comment: and if automatic update is disabled? what if the admin never visits the site? Anyway this specific way will let anyone download  free copy of the plugin as there is no check for license.

Comment: I´m sure those two things can be brought together in some way if you want to.