# How to notify wordpress instalation about my plugin update?

Tags: plugins, deployment

I've created my first plugin and made it public on the wordpress plugin repository, now i'm ready to release another version to this plugin and i made all steps that the guideline says and i've already deployed using `svn`.

But when i enter my wordpress installation there no notification about the update, how can i send this update notification for my plugin users?

I've came across with this answer; [How to notify my plugin users about new version releases?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/217113/how-to-notify-my-plugin-users-about-new-version-releases)
but it looks like a litle out-dated.

Comment: You need to check for updates, otherwise you'll need to ask .org support for how the plugin repo works. If you've done things correctly, then you do not need ot notify WP installs the plugin has been updated. Because of that, there is no notification step that you can take. Eitherway this is not the place to ask for help with the wordpress.org site itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the new version in the 'tag' folder of your repository. The folder name should be the same as the version number inside the readme file. Make sure that the version number has the same number of digits, as they are sorted numerically. Version 1.1 is 'lower than version 1.15, because the version number doesn't have the same number of decimals. I always label my versions 1.10, 1.11, 1.20, 1.21, etc.

If you have synced the repository correctly, you should get an email back from WP that the new version is available. Can take up to an hour.

I always put the latest version in the root of the repository, and in the 'trunk' folder of the repository, and then in the new version number folder in the 'tag' folder. Maybe redundant, but works for me.

So

```
-- (root) (latest version here)
    |--- trunk (latest version here)
    | --- tag
           \--- 1.00  (prior version)
           \--- 1.01  (latest version here)
```

etc.

If you do all that, then all users of your plugin will see the upgrade notice. Not right away (patience, grasshopper), but probably within an hour.

Comment: For reference the documentation for tagging a new version with SVN is here: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/how-to-use-subversion/#tagging-new-versions